# Configurable significance for numbers in java's String.format()?

Tags: java, string-formatting

I'm tasked with writing function to format a set (coordinate) of doubles with a configurable significance. I now have:

```
public String dPath(int sign) {
    return String.format ("%s %." + sign + "f %." + sign + "f", prefix, this.x, this.y);
}
```

which works:

```
Movement m = new Movement(3.14159265, 2.7654321);
Assert.assertEquals("m 3.142 2.765", m.dPath(3));
```

Is it possible to do it without String concatenation? Current implementation looks a bit unnatural, but that may also be attributed to the unnatural use case?

Comment: You could create your format string with `String.format()` :-)

Comment: `Assert.assertEquals("m 0.23", String.format("m %.%df", 0.2345d, 2));` fails on me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for good measure.

```
return String.format(String.format("%%s %%.%df %%.%df", sign, sign),
        prefix, this.x, this.y);
```

Comment: Ha, beat me to it! Anyway, this seems like it's not a major issue. The OP should pick whichever feels more natural. There isn't a nicer way to do it really.

Answer (score 1):

Maybee something like this?

```
public String dPath(int sign) 
{
    String pattern = "%s %.signf %.signf";
    pattern = pattern.replaceAll("sign", String.valueOf(sign));
    return String.format(pattern, prefix, this.x, this.y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One could use a MessageFormat, with for numbers a separate NumberFormat. The code is a bit much, but one nice aspect is the localisation: thousands separators, a decimal comma for French, and so on.

```
MessageFormat format = new MessageFormat("{0, string} {1, number} {2, number}");
if (0 > sign || sign > 10) {
    sign = 3;
}
DecimalFormat decF = new DecimalFormat(".##########".substring(0, sign + 1);
format.setFormatByArgumentIndex(1, decF);
format.setFormatByArgumentIndex(2, decF);
return format.format(prefix, this.x, this.y);
```